# How to autogenerate Python documentation using Sphinx when using dynamic classes and dynamic modules

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I currently have a use case where I am creating Python classes in modules using the following code.

```
...
module = type.ModuleType(module_name)
...
klass = type(name, (object, ), dict(__doc__='docstring'))
...
setattr(module, name, klass)
...
```

However Sphinx is not able to generate documentation for these classes. It is not even able to find the classes. Is there a way to add an extension to Sphinx to handle this use case? Thoughts?

The full minimum working example for this is located [here](https://github.com/kdheepak/dynamic-classes).

Comment: Are they generated when the module is imported?

Comment: Yes they are. The submodules are created in the [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/kdheepak/dynamic-classes/blob/master/modules/__init__.py) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following `automodule` directive in modules.rst:

```
.. automodule:: modules
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

But the qualified names of the dynamic modules are `modules.Module1` and `modules.Module2` (these names are added to `sys.modules` in _factory.py).

The following works for me:

```
.. automodule:: modules.Module1
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

.. automodule:: modules.Module2
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That solved it! So it appears the issue is then with `sphinx-apidoc`? Since I used that to generate the `modules.rst` file.

Comment: Yes, I think so. sphinx-apidoc looks for "normal" modules and is not clever enough to deduce that there are dynamically created modules.